# adding x-content-type-options nosniff results in blank page being displayed

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

My first question.  Just for reference, I support middleware and am not a developer.  I’m trying to get the – Header always set  X-content-type-options nosniff - working in the  IHS httpd.conf file.  The issue is - without the nosniff argument the page displays correctly.  However when I add the header a blank page is displayed.

Below are some of the response header values.   The content-length is non-empty and the return code is 200 so the content is there.
I believe the nosniff header is doing it’s job in that the content-type is text/html however the application server is returning test/javascript content (see below – Extract from the response), therefore it doesn’t display the page?

The Response header sets the following:

x-Content-Type-Options nosniff

x-Frame-Options DENY

content-type:  text/html; type=SSA; charset=UTF-8

content-length: 20000

Extract from the response:
script type="text/javascript"
src="/ab24/contenthandler/!xx/q/blahblah....."/script

I don’t believe it matters where I locate the header as I’ve tried it in both the ‘Main’ server section as well as the  section as I can see the header being set either way. 
I believe the correct solution would be to have the back end application server change its code to respond with the content-type header set to ‘text/javascript’?   However since I don’t have access to the code I’m trying to figure out if there is a way I can handle it in the httpd.conf file?

What I’ve tried thus far is since the config file has the TypesConfig conf/mimes.type  and the mod_mime.so module loaded I noticed there wasn’t a text/javascript entry in the file so I added it, restarted IHS but no luck, still displays a blank page :(.     Does anyone have any ideas if this could be handled somehow in the configuration file via some other directive(s), etc, or  is the only way with a new code deploy?

I did look at many of the other questions related to x-content-type-options but couldn’t find an answer to my question.